# Show that the derivative of a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-2x}{(2+x^2)^{n+1}}$ converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Consider the derivative series

$$
D = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-2x}{(2+x^2)^{n+1}}
$$
of
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{(2+x^2)^n}
$$

I have shown that $S$ converges by the use of Weiterstrass' M-test by saying that
as $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we must have that
$$
\frac{1}{(2+x^2)^n} \leq \frac{1}{n}
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This means that 
$$
\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{(2+x^2)^n} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
and from analysis we know that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
converges. But I am struggling to prove that $D$ converges uniformly. Do I have to use the same approach? I found that for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that 
$$
 \frac{-2x}{(2+x^2)^{n+1}} \leq \frac{1}{2^n}
$$
which is a geometric series that converges. Can I use this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x)=\frac{-2x}{(2+x^2)^{n+1}}$, then$$f'(x)=2 \left(x^2+2\right)^{-n-2} \left((2 n+1) x^2-2\right).$$So, the maximum of $|f|$ is attained when $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac2{2n+1}}$ and$$\left|f\left(\pm\sqrt{\frac2{2n+1}}\right)\right|=2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2 n+1}} \left(\frac{2}{2 n+1}+2\right)^{-n-1}.$$Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2 n+1}} \left(\frac{2}{2 n+1}+2\right)^{-n-1}=0,$$the convergence is uniform by the Weierstrass $M$-test.

Comment: So I am not able to use what I have written? I thought the approach was ok.

Comment: It depends. If your proof of the fact that$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R):\left|\frac{-2x}{(2+x^2)^{n+1}}\right|\leqslant\frac1{2^n}$$is correct (you did not show your proof), then everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks! I am not asked to prove that the $D$ converges uniformly but only to argue for. Would it be enough then? I am studying for my Analysis exam at the moment.

Comment: It will be enough **if** you justify correctly your inequality.

Comment: Would it be something like this: As $(2+x^2) > 2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we must have that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $ \left| \frac{-2x}{(2+x^2)^{n+1}} \right| \leq \frac{1}{2^n}$?

Comment: From the fact that $2+x^2>2$, what I am able to deduce is that$$\left|\frac{-2x}{(2+x^2)^{n+1}}\right|\leqslant\frac{|x|}{2^n}.$$How do you make that $|x|$ go away?

Comment: I see that. I am not sure then.

Comment: It is easy to prove that$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R):\left|\frac{-2x}{1+x^2}\right|\leqslant1.$$Your inequality follows from this fact.

Comment: Does it follow from that $1+x^2 \geq -2x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which means that the denominator always will be bigger than the numerator. Thus the fraction can will always be less or equal to one?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you Jose. You have been of great help! :)

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.